# Loader which also shows the percent loaded for webpage

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a loader on my website which loads all the photos of the webpage before showing any text, pictures and other content. So I put the code for a background, main-wrapper(with design), etc along with all the images in the page (`style="width:0;height:0;visibility:hidden;"` and other things to make them invisible). With that I put something saying Loading.......

**HTML:**

```
<body onLoad="load()">
<div class="main-wrapper" id="main-wrapper">
     <p>Loading.....</p>
</div>
<img src="xxxxx" class="hidden">
<img src="xxxxx" class="hidden">
<img src="xxxxx" class="hidden">
<img src="xxxxx" class="hidden">
```

**Javascript:**

```
function load()
{
document.getElementById('main-wrapper').innerHTML = "Text I Want <img src="x"";>
}
```

This made the text I want to display once all the images are loaded. Now I have no problem in writing the content I want in .innerHTML="";.

Please tell me a way so that I could also tell the percent loaded using any coding language. Please also tell me if there is a better way to do it, but while telling the percent loaded.

Comment: What percentage you'd like to show? The loaded_piece/pieces, or loaded_MB/all_MB? You could approach this from a different angle, and load all the images with AJAX calls, in that way you can keep tract of the loading process, and after all is loaded move them into place.

Comment: Percent loaded of the whole webpage.

Comment: In that case you have to count up all the images sizes server-side, and if possible add also the html size to that. On loading the page load the images using ajax calls (preferably with jQuery, with that you can [listen to the loaded event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) on each image), one after another, and as you ask for the next picture you also pass the percentage value back from server with the next image's url. And then listen to the loaded event, and go into a loop until you reach 100%

Comment: Sorry but i've got no idea what would my images' size server-side and html are. Plus, as for the calls you're talking about, please elabourate with script so that a newbie to jQuery can understand it.

Comment: @jeroen gave a really good example in the meantime, that would have been mine as well (in the logic part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution, just counting the number of images and not taking into account the size of the images would be something like (just a simple example...):

```
function loadPage(html) {
  // html contains the html to add to #main-wrapper

  // put the html in an element to count the images in it
  var el = $("<div>").html(html);
  var imgCount = el.find("img").length;
  var count = 0;
  var percentage = 0;

  $("img", el).load(function() {
    count++;
    if (imgCount === count) {
      $("#main-wrapper").html(html);
    } else {
      percentage = (count / imgCount) * 100;
      $("#main-wrapper").html("loading ("+ percentage + "%) ...");
    }
  });
}
```

It will be difficult to get the image sizes before they are loaded; I have not tried that recently but before it was easy to get the sizes in firefox, but impossible to get them in for example webkit.

Comment: what does 'length' in el.find("img").length mean?

Comment: @X Phoenix `el.find("img")` finds all images, `length` gives you the total number of images found.

Comment: And as you were doubting about browser support is that true(Please tell me i can test).

Comment: And does this method give for eg. if there are 10 imgs, and 2 are loaded, percent = 20%.

Comment: @X Phoenix 7 This works cross-browser, getting the sizes of the images does (did?) not but I am not using that.